# What are the best practices for organizing the dimens.xml file?

Tags: android

My dimens file gets pretty big for a medium size app...
Do you guys use generic dimen items like: activity_horizontal_margin, activity_horizontal_margin_x2, or do you name them according to the layout they are used in:

> "dimen name="activity_main_button_height" 
>   -30dp 
>   /dimen"
>   ???

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really have that many dimen resources? You know you don't have to create a new dimen resource for every little padding in each layout. Moving every value into the dimen resources just clutters your  app as you have experienced first hand. The important values, espeically those you need for resource selection are supposed to be in the dimen resources, the rest doesn't really matter.

Comment: @XaverKapeller, baloney. Layout matters, especially when you're designing for many different devices. The cost of having to refactor every single layout in the app because of a new screen size or format is huge.

Comment: To the OP: @AlexBalo's advice in the answer below is good: Use multiple xml files for dimensions, organizing as many as possible into "general" dimensions, such as `button_padding_left` and `button_padding_right`. Add one xml file for each activity and related fragments.

Comment: thx for your answers! I'm gonna go with 322go!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually create different dimen.xml depending on each layout and then a common dimen file for dimensions used all over the apps (let's say shared dimens).

Hope it helps.